# Google scripts with cloud external editor on mobile

Tags: mobile, google-apps-script, jupyter-notebook

I’m trying to figure out how to code Google App scripts from a mobile device and I’ve narrowed in on some solutions, but have not quite found one that works.

The first step is to find a way to code app scripts from an online editor. I already do online coding through the iOS app Juno, which has an editor for Jupyter notebooks stored in the cloud on CoCalc.

Unfortunately, Jupyter notebooks do not natively code App scripts Java-like programming. So, i’d have to figure out how to deploy scripts from a python environment.

Google does have documentation on deploying app scripts with python, but require Clasp and other installs, which I’ve yet to figure out how to install in a Jupyter notebook.

I wish I could set up a cloud doc to share here, but I don’t have even the beginning elements of attempt yet. So, I hope this question is enough for someone to give me direction.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Android has [tag:termux]